# Ember.js handle authorization via provider with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, client-server

Cheers! I have Ember + Rails app, Rails-side provides me a link with json:

```
http://location/api/users/vk_auth_url.json
```

And it's content is:

```
"http://location/users/auth/vkontakte"
```

How can I get access to it from my application ember's template?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Jesse Wolgamott, I did it like this in view (temporary in application view):

```
Bandyard.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  authUrl: null,

  didInsertElement: function(){
      var url = $("body").data("auth-url");
      this.set('authUrl', url);
    }
});
```

And in the template:

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{unbound view.authUrl}}">Sign up</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way I've found is to add this to the body.

```
<body data-auth-url="http://location/users/auth/vkontakte"></body>
```

Then you can grab that and use it with a simple:

```
$("body").data("auth-url")
```

Comment: @Nikita Yeah -- until some future guidance from the ember gang, I fully endorse this.